# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) in Bind function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-events

I'm trying to send a call using Ajax but in Chrome it is rising error but in Firefox there is no error. But still it can't calling the method. I tried to record my call in Firebug but there is no call request in Firebug. So that's the reason there is no error in Firefox.

**Index.chshtml** code is below

```
function onLoad(e) {

    var grid = $(this).data("tGrid");
    //bind to the context menu of the Grid's header
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find(".t-grid-header").bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
        //wait for the menu to be generated
        setTimeout(function () {
            // bind to the checkboxes change event. The context menu has ID in the format "GridName" + "_contextmenu"
            $('#globalsearchgrid_contextMenu :checkbox').change(function () {
                debugger;
                var $checkbox = $(this);
                // the checked state will determine if the column has been shown or hidden
                var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
                // get the index and the corresponding column from the Grid's column collection
                var columnIndex = $(this).data("field");

                var request = "{'columnIndex':'" + columnIndex + "'value':'" + checked + "'}";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../../GlobalSearch/SaveColumnInfo",
                    data: request,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) { },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(error.responseTextss);
                    }

                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**Controller method**

```
 public JsonResult SaveColumnInfo(string columnIndex, string value)
    {
        CookieHelper helper=new CookieHelper();
        helper.UpdateCookie(int.Parse(columnIndex), value.ToString());

        return Json("Success");
    }
```

**Error in Chrome**

> POST http‍://localhost:3577/GlobalSearch/SaveColumnInfo 500 (Internal Server Error)
> jQuery.ajaxTransport.send
> jQuery.extend.ajax
> (anonymous function)
> jQuery.event.handle
> jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle

Comment: You are doing a post. Did you mark SaveColumnInfo as HttpPost?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with HttpPost but no success. In other pages of mu application I'm using the same ajax call method without HttpPost attribute  and its working if fine at ther.

Comment: I'dont think so, ../../GlobalSearch/SaveColumnInfo is wrong! You cant type this kind of url! /GlobalSearch/SaveColumnInfo should work!

Comment: well in other calling method I'm using the same and it is correct. However I've used without ../.. it is also working. But still same erro. I'm editing my question for error detail.

Comment: There is issue with my value string. Thanx Fals for your help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The 500 code would normally indicate an error on the server, not anything with your code. Some thoughts

- Talk to the server developer for more info. You can't get more info directly.
- Verify your arguments into the call (values). Look for anything you might think could cause a problem for the server process. The process should not die and should return you a better code, but bugs happen there also.
- Could be intermittent, like if the server database goes down. May be worth trying at another time.

Comment: I changed my fancy names for id being passed to just "id" and mine worked. go figure

Comment: In my case, I clicked on the error that was showing in console i.e. http://vuela.dev/api/calendar/create 500 (Internal Server Error). clicking it, I was taken to Network tab where it showed different files, their statuses, sizes and all that stuff. then i clicked on a file that had 500 status & it showed me error details from where I figured there was a constructor running with bad credentials. NOTE: I am using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Spent 30mins with this to only find out that: that data name in the Ajax, must be the same with the variable name you use in your controller. if not specify it like `data: {columnindex: request}`

Comment: solution #1:

Install the required packages by running the composer command from the the root of the project:

sudo composer install

solution #2:

For solving the problem i ran the following commands through terminal.

sudo chmod  -R  755  MYlaravel_project
and then type below to allow laravel to write file to storage folder

chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/root/dir/
chmod -R 775 /bootstrap
chmod -R 775 /storage

Comment: id which was an INT was null and asp-route-id was throwing an exception on the server in my case

Comment: Mine turned out to be php version error, increased to higher version (8.2) and things were okay.