# CSS not loading in godaddy

Tags: html, css

I have researched this topic in stackoverflow and tried the solutions offered and still do not get my problem solved. I have two sites in godaddy constructed exactly the same, but one loads the css and the other does not. The site not loading css loads perfectly well in free hostings. I have tried checking case sensitive, path and folder issues, permissions and everything I can think of and still do not get the css loading.  The css is in the css folder and everything seems ok. Here is my code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css"/>
```

url not working in godaddy: www.progeneticlagarita.com

url working: www.progeneticlagarita.x10host.com

Thanks in advance for any light on this!!

Answer (score 1):

Check that your Firewall Caching is not active. In GoDaddy this can prevent your CSS changes from being loaded to the live site. I had this problem as well and finally got help through support.

In GoDaddy account:
Go to My Products > scroll down to Web Security And Backups > click Manage for the Web Security Premium package > under Firewall click Details > click Settings tab > then click Performance tab > then set Caching Level to Disabled.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure:

1) Can you put absolute paths to the css files instead of relative paths and check. For example: `http://www.progeneticlagarita.com/css/styles.css`

2) Also try opening this absolute path in a browser directly.

Comment: Hi BlueKlip, I did check bot and I got "Internal Server Error"...error 500 to be exact...

Answer (score 0):

One potential cause since those are not the same domains, is there are two separate DNS Zone Files to manage for each might.  I pinged both domain names and received two seperate IP addresses:

[image]

I'm not a 100% sure if this will solve your issue, but if your website is only on one server, the fact only one of the IPs is working might help you track down your issue.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried contacting the customer support? HTTP ERROR 500 is server error, it's either the web server config disallow you to access the link/path of your assets or a database error. I'm no server admin pro but my answer is based on my previous experiences and what I did to debug it.

Some related info:

> [Error 500](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm) and [The server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180684/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-500-internal-ser)

Comment: Hi Vainglory07, I am no server admin either, but I see I get error 500...I checked with customer support (I´ve called 3 times) and they say they can´t figure out what's wrong. Error 500 is on their end, right? (I am reading your links, thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common reasons for Error 500 is a misconfigured `.htaccess` file. This would also explain why your site works on one server and not on another, because different servers can have different configurations.

Check if you have a `.htaccess` file inside your `/css/` directory. Remember that this file is hidden by default, make sure you enable "Show hidden files" if available. If no such file is available, see if a parent directory contains a `.htaccess` file with reference to the `/css/` directory. Even the smallest syntax error will give you an error, usually a Error 500. Try commenting out some of the lines by adding `#` in front, or rename the entire file to something else (remember to make a backup of any file before editing).

The reason I think the problem has to do with the `/css/` folder is that only this folder seems to be unavailable. If you try visiting http://www.progeneticlagarita.com/img/, a 403 Forbidden error is shown (directory listing not allowed).

http://www.progeneticlagarita.com/css/, however, gives a different error: 500 Internal Server Error.

A couple of suggestions to look for in your `.htaccess` file:

- `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 php`

  This (or similar) command will enable a specific PHP version on your server. This particular command works on HostGator, but NOT for GoDaddy.
- `Option Includes`

  > If you use use "Option Includes," "Options -Includes," or "Options +Includes" in your .htaccess file, your site might display a "500 - Internal Server Error." ([GoDaddy support](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6945/issues-with-server-side-includes-and-htaccess-files))

Comment: Thank you Johanpw!!!! wow this solved it. The problem was in the .htaccess file that was in the /css/ directory file. I eliminated this file and voila, site fixed. I am totally grateful!!!!!!! :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad the solution worked. A bad `.htaccess` file is usually worse than none...

Comment: hi @Sara, make sure to upvote (click the up arrow on) any answers you find useful and to accept this answer, since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css"/>
```

This issue is related to the MIME types that are specific in the Godadddy hosting.
under the Web server settings, one has to define the types of MIME used. to make it simple MIME types are the types of files or media we use in our code. It can be a simple CSS file or an image or instance.

I prefer to use all major MIME types.  all of which are listed in this [link](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/default-mime-types-windows-3821)

On more precise understanding on windows settings  - check [this](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/default-mime-types-windows-3821)