# Accessing Airtable from Codesandbox.io

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, airtable, codesandbox

I literally copied the snippets from Airtable API, for example:

```
var Airtable = require('airtable');
var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'}).base('BASE_KEY');

base('Test').find('RECORD_ID', function(err, record) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    console.log('Retrieved', record.id);
});
```

However, the only error I get is:

```
Error: Internal XMLHttpRequest Error
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: i have just airtable in codesandbox environment and there is no error, record is retreiving successfully.

Comment: @Edgar did this get resolved? It'd be good to know whether it was temporary issues with Airtable server-side or if you you needed to make any changes to your code. That error msg would normally indicate 500 Internal Server Error (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45960144/8012789) so I'm assuming it was Airtable's issue and nothing you'd done wrong... please can you confirm?